# Utilizar o dropbox como repositório de projetos NetBeans 8 no Windows

Tags: java, git, netbeans

Estou utilizando o  NetBeans 8 em meus projetos e gostaria muito de utilizar o dropbox como versionador. Eu configuro o repositório no Dropbox mas com o diretório do projeto em outro caminho. Pode ser que eu esteja confundindo as coisas, mas o que é enviado para a pasta do dropbox é somente o diretório .git.[image: Inicio o projeto e seleciono o diretório do git]

No entanto, o projeto não é enviado para o dropbox, o que fica é somente o .git o que impossibilita que uma pessoa que possua acesso a pasta do meu dropbox inicie o projeto, atualize e etc.
Procurei por tutoriais e informações, mas tudo por linha de comando, tem realmente que ser assim por linha de comando?
Desculpe não ter nada de código para enviar.

Comment: Não entendi. O .git é enviado ou não para o dropbox? Vc precisa somente dele para poder trabalhar em equipe no msm projeto. Ah, e usar o dropbox para isso pode ser uma ideia terrível, pois ao sincronizar ele não garante a atomicidade da operação, o que pode estragar completamente o seu repositório.

Comment: Me tira uma duvida, o que vai para o repositório de versões é somente o .git? o problema é que quando eu tento clonar não da certo, os arquivos do projeto não estão lá.

Comment: Sim, somente o git basta. Voce deve estar cometendo algum erro no seu processo. Vc precisa de um .git local, na mesma pasta do seu projeto, e vc pode ter um remoto, que vc atualiza ele via push

Comment: O .git no local do projeto existe sim, eu somente utilizei os recursos do NetBeans, não tentei via linha de comando, seria melhor tentar por linha de comando?

Comment: Tanto faz, mas em algum momento vc precisa fazer um push pra atualizar o remoto, no seu caso na pasta do dropbox. Ah, e considere nao usar o dropbox para isso, veja o bitbucket que oferece repositorios privados gratuitos.

Comment: Não conhecia o bitbucket, minha primeira ideia era usar o dropbox por ser free. A sua dica ai valeu o ano, rsrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das principais vantagens do `Git` é o fato dele ser uma ferramenta de versionamento distribuída. Isto é, cada desenvolvedor pode contribuir com código para outros repositórios e ao mesmo tempo pode manter um repositório público em que outros podem basear seu trabalho e que eles podem contribuir. [[1]](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-Distribu%C3%ADdo-Fluxos-de-Trabalho-Distribu%C3%ADdos)

A ideia de utilizar o *Dropbox* como centralizador do repositório, permitindo que outras pessoas com acesso a este possam também trabalhar no projeto não é ruim, mas o resultado pode não ser o que você espera. Pode ocorrer o risco de dois developers estarem utilizando ao mesmo tempo, e um *commit* anule o outro.

Trabalhar com o `Git` utilizando um repositório remoto (desconsiderando Dropbox, OneDrive, etc) é o ideal nesses casos. Conforme citado pelo Math, o [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) é uma opção para repositórios privados gratuitos. O [Github](https://github.com/) também é uma alternativa, sendo este privado apenas em caso de assinatura de um plano.